# How to style a QWidget when it has no parent

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets

I have a program that can load plugin modules and these plugin modules I don't have much control over (outside of instructing customers about guidelines on how to create their modules).

I'm, however, trying to create some Style Themes (e.g. 'lightTheme' and 'darkTheme') for my application that I'd also like to propagate to any UI elements that may be created in any plugins.

Here's my problem, in one of the plugins I noticed that a bare QWidget (e.g. `QWidget *widget = new QWidget();` was created that has no parent and I'm trying to figure out how to style this window.

Qt in this case treats this view kind of like a QDialog, however in the stylesheet I need to use QWidget to style this view (QDialog doesn't do anything). As you might expect adding style to QWidget (e.g. `QWidget { background-color: black; }` with cause a whole host of other style changes throughout my program that I don't want.

So what I'm looking for is how to "style a QWidget that doesn't have a parent".

I was expecting to do something like:

```
parent > QWidget { background-color: black; }
```

But I can't figure out what to put for the 'parent' since I know this widget has no parent.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is this widget being deleted if it has no parent? Do you have access to the widget?

Comment: Even if it did have a direct visual/widget parent, how would you style it? And wouldn't you need to make exceptions every time a plugin author does something different? Doesn't seem sustainable, though w/out a more concrete example it's hard to judge. There's nothing inherently wrong with `QWidget {background-color: black; }` if your theme is dark and you want all widgets to have the same background color. OTOH widget authors can always override the app-wide style anyway. A top-level `QWidget` is _not_ a `QDialog` even if it appears to act like one.

Comment: @btse the plugin interface has "create" and "destroy" calls and so the user is implementing their own deletion. And no I don't have access to the widget.

Comment: @Maxim my intention was to have some general styling that would propagate across to any plugins (I agree that it won't always work for every situation and that it can be overriden). But was surprised that I couldn't specify styling to "a QWidget that has no parent".